# Linq expression meaning

Tags: .net, linq

```
if (regionTerritory.Any(m => m.Region == int.Parse(region.RegionCode)))
{
    // region exists, add territory
    regionTerritory.First(m => m.Region == int.Parse(region.RegionCode)).Territories.Add(int.Parse(region.TerritoryCode), region.TerritoryName);
}
```

Can anybody tell me what does this means ?
also what is **m** in above code and **Any**, **First** and **Add**  ?

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: As an aside, if you're new to lambda expressions, I would suggest you learn about those before you go much further with LINQ.

Answer (score 3):

`m` is the parameter to the lambda expression. It will be called with each element in the collection (as far as necessary). This is an inefficient way of writing the code, however. It would be better to use:

```
int regionCode = int.Parse(region.RegionCode);
var targetRegion = regionTerritory.FirstOrDefault(m => m.Region == regionCode);
if (targetRegion != null)
{
    targetRegion.Territories.Add(regionCode, region.TerritoryName);
}
```

Now:

- We only parse `region.RegionCode` once
- We only need to find the matching region in `regionTerritory` once (and then add to it)

Comment: could you please explain what is happening in above code?

Comment: @NileshChandane: No, because you haven't said which part you don't understand. As I mentioned in the comment on the question, if you don't know what lambda expressions are, that's the first thing to learn.

Answer (score 0):

You are new to LINQ I guess, I would recommend you to create a free account in below mentioned website and watch the video for few hours. You feel excited about LINQ.

Website : **www.pluralsight.com**
Search for :**LINQ Fundamentals with C# 6.0**, by Scott Allen

There you will find a clear , correct answer to your question.